An Optimization Problem With Permutation Function
When I tried to solve an one-to-one assignment problem, I constructed it as the following optimization problem, which is a min-max optimization problem with the optimization objective being functions.
Define a permutation mapping $\sigma(\cdot):\mathcal{V}\longmapsto\mathcal{V}$ with $\mathcal{V}=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$, which can transform an integer in $\mathcal{V}$ consisting of $1,2,\dots,N$ into another integer. For instance, given a identity mapping $\sigma_0(\cdot)$, one has that $\sigma_0(i)=i$ for $i\in\mathcal{V}$. Given a constant matrix $T$ and its element can be denoted as $T_{i,j}$.
Now, I want to solve the optimization problem $\min_{\sigma}\max_{i\in\mathcal{V}}T_{\sigma(i),i}$, and what method should I use to solve it?

Take a square matrix of zeros and ones. Can you find a permutation of the columns such that the diagonal has no zero? If so, you can easily find an answer for your problem

Could you explain it in more detail? I cannot understand it.

Do you mean "transform an integer into another integer"?  I don't understand why you write "transform a permutation into another permutation".

Please [edit] your post to address the feedback provided.  Just deleting the word "interesting" from the title is not sufficient.

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  For $i,j\in \mathcal{V}$, let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether $\sigma(i)=j$.  Let decision variable $z$ represent $\max_{i\in \mathcal{V}} T_{\sigma(i),i}$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in \mathcal{V}} x_{ij} &=1 &&\text{for $i\in \mathcal{V}$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{i\in \mathcal{V}} x_{ij} &=1 &&\text{for $j\in \mathcal{V}$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_{j\in \mathcal{V}} T_{ji} x_{ij} &\le z &&\text{for $i\in \mathcal{V}$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraints \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} enforce that $\sigma$ is a permutation.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the minimax objective.

Thank you for your solutions! Can such a mixed integer linear programming problem get globally optimal solutions by the existing solvers? And how long do these solvers take?

Yes, MILP solvers can return globally optimal solutions. The time depends on the problem size and the solver. Do you have sample data you can share?

I am so sorry I cannot provide a sample of a large enough scale. Could you recommend a MILP solver so I can construct some simple samples to try it?

I recommend SAS. Disclaimer: I work for SAS.

Thank you very much!

Let $S_m$ be the $0$-$1$ matrix with $S_{i,j} = 1$ if and only if $T_{i,j} \leq m$. Then $\min_\sigma \max_i T_{\sigma(i),i} \leq m$ if and only if the bipartite graph whose bipartite adjacency matrix is $S_m$ has a perfect matching. To find $\min_\sigma \max_i T_{\sigma(i),i}$, simply try as $m$ every $T_{i,j}$ in order and use your favorite efficient algorithm for bipartite perfect matching.

Thank you for your solutions! I have one question and want to ask you in more detail: 1) Could you explain how to transform the problem $\min_{\sigma}\max_{i}T_{\sigma(i),i}\leq m$
into the perfect matching $S_m$?

@JiayuZou you want some $\sigma$ for which every $T_{\sigma(i),i}$ is at most $m$, so we should only 'use' the entries of $T$ which are at most $m$ --- this is given by $S_m$. A perfect matching in a bipartite graph can be identified with a permutation using the bipartite adjacency matrix of the graph in precisely the way you want.

Thank you very much!

Thanks to the idea of Bob Krueger, it seems that I have found an algorithm: Given a $m=\min_{i,j}T_{i,j}$, let $S_m$ be the 0-1 matrix with $S_{i,j}=1$ if and only if $T_{i,j}\leq m$. Then, look for a perfect matching of $S_m$. If the matching cannot be found, then let $m$ be the second-smallest $T_{i,j}$ (If it cannot be found, then third, fourth...); Else, find all of the matchings and pick the minimal matching with maximal $T_{i,j}$ from it.
